# How to Align an image to the center of a screen using SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-view

I'm trying to align an image to the center of the screen in Swift/SwiftUI.

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Color.white
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                Image("1Pzpe")
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width-3, height: geometry.size.width-3, alignment: .center)
                Spacer()
            }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PGrN.png)
Instead of being centered, my image goes a little more to the right. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Did you tried with no spacer and in a zstack including the vstack ?

Comment: The `Color` in the `HStack` is likely pushing it over. I wouldn't use `GeometryReader` in this context -- use `padding` instead. Also, you *probably* want `.resizable()` on your `Image`

Answer (score 2):

Using this modifier will let you center images

```
extension Image {
    func centerCropped() -> some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            self
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
            .clipped()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In Kenton's example, the image is being centered by the .frame modifier.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need GeometryReader for this case

You are putting a Color view aside the image so it would never be centered
you probably just need a ZStack if you want the image over the color

```
ZStack{
        Color.white
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        Image(systemName: "iphone")
    }
```

to center a image in the view you only need to put the image there also you don't need GeometryReader to fill the image just use `.resizable()` `.scaledToFit()` and `.padding(3)`

```
ZStack{
        Color.white
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        Image(systemName: "square.fill")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .padding(3)
            .foregroundColor(.red)
    }
```